# Using libgdx with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

According to libgdx wiki (http://goo.gl/fJgSab):

> Android Studio is fully compatible with libGDX's Gradle based build
>   system.

How exactly should one proceed to import the Android project generated by libgdx into Android Studio?

Comment: Android studio is based on intellij idea, try intellij idea community which has a better support for java projects. There is an option in libgdx project setup which generates .ipr file which is entry point for intellij projects.

Answer (score 2):

If you have created the project using libGDX gradle build system, you will have a file build.gradle in the root directory. Just open Android studio and import project and select this file. It will automatically fetch required resources and create your project structure in Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import your gradle project into Android Studio

[Migrating from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html#Export)

> Import into Android Studio

1. In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see
   the Welcome to Android Studio window.
2. Click Import Project.
3. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select the build.gradle file and click OK.
4. In the following dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click
   OK. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)

I would also like to recommend using IntelliJ for libgdx over Android Studio as IntelliJ will allow you to work on Desktop and Html versions of you project as well.

Comment: +Zyion This didn't work. By the way, I'm not exporting anything from Eclipse. I'm talking about the project built by libgdx setup.

Comment: You generate your project with the libgdx setup ui then open android studio and select import project and select your build gradle. Can you post some more info on what is going wrong or errors you are getting?  I think when libgdx say android studio I think they really mean IntelliJ Idea.