# Can't setup android project using libGDX

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to make an Android app using [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) but I'm stuck at the setup. I've setup the project using the [libGDX Setup App](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html).

There I specify what I want to use and I click **Generate**.

[image]

Then I open IntelliJ and import the build.grade file just like the Setup App tells me. This gives me all the files I want and I try to add an Android Application configuration. I select the **android module** in the list but this gives me an error saying

> Default Activity not found.

If I then switch from **Launch default Activity** to **Launch** and specify my own, then I can't choose the one I want, *android/src/com/my_project/android/AndroidLauncher.java*.

The [libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA) says

> **Android**: A configuration for the Android project should be automatically created on project import. As such, you only have to select the configuration and run it!

What am I missing?

Comment: In Eclipse I use something like this, Import -> 'Gradle Project' 'Build Model' have installed a plugin for Gradle, but not if it be the same in your case, I found that here is something like maybe you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235493/using-libgdx-with-android-studio

Comment: I know you said you imported the build.gradle file, but I had the exact same issue as you because I accidentally opened it instead of importing it. Make sure you choose Import Project from the File menu, not Open.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Tried it again and still doesn't work :/

Comment: You have the Android Gradle plugin installed in IntelliJ, right? Can't think of what else might cause this. When I import a new libgdx project, the Android run configuration is already there.

Comment: I have the "Android" plugin seen on the last page of Intellij's Plugin Configuration Wizard, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can just have it deploy to the emulator/device by choosing **Do not launch Activity**. Then you can just launch it from the app icon.

Answer (score 0):

With latest libgdx and Intellij Idea 13.x I was unable to configure a project automatically.

After tracing the problem, it seems that something was wrong with the gradle version Intellij Idea is using. I tried to resolve that by updating gradle and altering the PATH variable, but that didn't help.

I ended up manually importing the module into the project and building the project using gradlew.

So now everything "kinda works" when building from command line.